# dynamoose throws TypeError

Tags: typescript, dynamoose

Somehow the most basic dynamoose example throws following error:

```
Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

Code:

```
import * as dynamoose from 'dynamoose';
import { Document } from 'dynamoose/dist/Document';

type User = {
  id: string;
  createdAt: number;
  updatedAt: number;
};

interface UserDocument extends Document, User {}

const UserSchema = new dynamoose.Schema(
  {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      index: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);

const UserModel = dynamoose.model<UserDocument>('Strung-Users', UserSchema, {
  create: false,
  waitForActive: false,
});

(async () => {
  console.log('START');
  const user = await UserModel.query('id').eq('userId').exec();

  console.log('END');
})();
```

Any ideas? The error happens in the `moveParameterNames` function in the `DocumentRetriever.js` file. But I don't really know what causes the error in the first place.

#### Solution

As pointed out in the comments. Removing `index: true` resolves the issue.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why do you have a local index on `id`? `id` is your hashKey in this case. Not sure what the purpose of having it also be an index is.

Comment: https://github.com/dynamoose/dynamoose/issues/1303

Comment: @CharlieFish Thank you!